# Access: Dlookup between 2 columns and multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access

I am relatively new with Dlookup in access.

I have 2 tables

Table 1

empname |   Doctype  | Average

Table 2

 Function | Ranking | bottomavg | topavg

I am writing a query and placing a relationship between function and doc type. I am pulling emp name, Doctype, average, and Score(renamed from  Ranking). I am looking for employee score based on their average and where it falls in between bottomavg and topavg.

As an Expression, I wrote `Score: DLookUp("Ranking","Table 2","" & [Average] & "Between Bottomavg And Topavg")`. it works but it is not seeing the different doc types.

I tried `score: DLookUp("Ranking","table 2","" & [Average] & "Between Bottomavg And Topavg" And [doctype]="&[function]&")` and it did not work.

What am I missing to link Doc type to function?

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes and `&` are all wrong. In addition I am not sure `BETWEEN` can be used the way you are trying to use it. Assuming your logic is correct and your syntax is the only problem and all your fields are numeric, this should work:

```
DLookUp("Ranking","table 2",[Average] & ">=Bottomavg And " & [Average] & "<=Topavg And " & [doctype] & "=Function")
```

With BETWEEN assuming Erik von Asmuth is correct and it works:

```
DLookUp("Ranking","table 2",[Average] & " BETWEEN Bottomavg And Topavg And " & [doctype] & "=Function")
```

Comment: Between can work in that way (and if you use it, you only have to refer to `[Average]` once). You might consider not removing it in your answer.

Comment: Yes all the fields are numeric, the doc type and function relationship should be link when they are the same eg doctype corrections, function = corrections

Comment: Where are you trying to use the expression. It will only work in a query that has `Table 1` as source. What are the exact data types of all the fields being used?

Comment: I am using the expression in a query in a field , when I select table 1 as a source, it comes up with the error: 

extra ) in query expression 'DLookUp("Ranking","table 2",[Average] & " BETWEEN Bottomavg And Topavg And " & [doctype] & "=Function")

Comment: Table 1
empname -short text
Doctype - short text
Average- number

Table 2
Function - Short text
Ranking - number
bottomavg - number
topavg - number

Comment: On problem for sure is that not all fields are numerical after all. Change the ending to `...And '" & [doctype] & "'=Function")` effectively enclosing `doctype` in single quotes. This will also break if you have any `doctype` or `Function` values with single quotes in them.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @SunKnight0 I added the single commas but it is still showing #error
`DLookUp("Ranking","table 2",[Average] & " BETWEEN Bottomavg And Topavg And '" & [doctype] & "'=Function")`